# Greg Youngs EventStore on Azure with Mono - Http not working

Tags: events, azure, mono

I have installed Greg Youngs EventStore on an azure virtual server with ubuntu as described here: [Setup EventStore on Windows Azure](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/wiki/Setup-EventStore-on-Windows-Azure)

The EventStore is running and I can connect to it using the .Net Api but the http server is not working at all. The web interface does not work as well as the atom api. I am getting no answer from the server. There is nothing in the log. Port forwarding seems to work as the tcp endpoint is working.

This is the log:

```
[53170,01,18:13:00.010] MessageHierarchy initialization took 00:00:00.1765448.

[53170,01,18:13:03.093] CACHED TFChunk #0-0 (chunk-000000.000000) in 00:00:00.3169408.

[53170,01,18:13:03.341] Starting MiniWeb for /web/es/js/projections ==> /home/azureuser/EventStore/bin/eventstore/release/anycpu/singlenode-web/js/projections

[53170,01,18:13:03.341] Starting MiniWeb for /web/es/js/projections/v8/Prelude ==> /home/azureuser/EventStore/bin/eventstore/release/anycpu/Prelude

[53170,01,18:13:03.342] Starting MiniWeb for /web/es/js/projections/resources ==> /home/azureuser/EventStore/bin/eventstore/release/anycpu/web-resources/js

[53170,01,18:13:03.343] Binding MiniWeb to /web/es/js/projections/{*remaining_path}

[53170,01,18:13:03.343] Binding MiniWeb to /web/es/js/projections/v8/Prelude/{*remaining_path}

[53170,01,18:13:03.343] Binding MiniWeb to /web/es/js/projections/resources/{*remaining_path}

[53170,01,18:13:03.348] Starting MiniWeb for /web ==> /home/azureuser/EventStore/bin/eventstore/release/anycpu/singlenode-web

[53170,01,18:13:03.348] Starting MiniWeb for /web/es ==> /home/azureuser/EventStore/bin/eventstore/release/anycpu/es-common-web

[53170,01,18:13:03.348] Binding MiniWeb to /web/{*remaining_path}

[53170,01,18:13:03.348] Binding MiniWeb to /web/es/{*remaining_path}

[53170,01,18:13:03.348] Starting MiniWeb for /web/users ==> /home/azureuser/EventStore/bin/eventstore/release/anycpu/Users/web

[53170,01,18:13:03.348] Binding MiniWeb to /web/users/{*remaining_path}

[53170,10,18:13:03.384] ========== [#############:2113] SYSTEM INIT...

[53170,08,18:13:03.457] TableIndex initialization...

[53170,08,18:13:03.472] ReadIndex building...

[53170,10,18:13:03.502] Starting Normal TCP listening on TCP endpoint: ###############:1113.

[53170,10,18:13:03.568] SLOW BUS MSG [MainBus]: SystemInit - 115ms. Handler: TcpService.

[53170,10,18:13:03.641] Starting HTTP server on [####################]...

[53170,10,18:13:03.646] HTTP server is up and listening on [#######################]

[53170,10,18:13:03.646] SLOW BUS MSG [MainBus]: SystemInit - 77ms. Handler: HttpService.

[53170,10,18:13:03.713] SLOW QUEUE MSG [MainQueue]: SystemInit - 296ms. Q: 0/1012.

[53170,08,18:13:05.878] ReadIndex Rebuilding Done: total processed 33820 records, time elapsed: 00:00:02.4055370.

[53170,10,18:13:05.882] ========== [##############:2113] SYSTEM START....

[53170,08,18:13:05.882] SLOW QUEUE MSG [StorageWriterQueue]: SystemInit - 2488ms. Q: 0/0.

[53170,10,18:13:05.889] ========== [#############:2113] PRE-MASTER STATE, WAITING FOR CHASER TO CATCH UP...

[53170,10,18:13:05.894] ========== [#############:2113] IS WORKING!!! SPARTA!!!

[53170,08,18:13:06.024] === Writing E3@248463988:{d52679ba-8314-479e-8d9c-9911094d17a8} (previous epoch at 301989).

[53170,12,18:13:06.029] SLOW BUS MSG [manager input bus]: ReadStreamEventsBackwardCompleted - 60ms. Handler: ProjectionManager.

[53170,12,18:13:06.029] SLOW QUEUE MSG [Projections Master]: ReadStreamEventsBackwardCompleted - 64ms. Q: 0/4.

[53170,08,18:13:06.122] === Update Last Epoch E3@248463988:{d52679ba-8314-479e-8d9c-9911094d17a8} (previous epoch at 301989).

[53170,13,18:13:06.157] Creating an event distribution point at 'C:0/P:-1'
```

Does someone had similar problems?

My config:

```
{
    "db": "/mnt/datadrive/eventStore/db",
    "logsDir": "/mnt/datadrive/eventStore/logs",
    "ip": "10.26.222.3",
    "httpPrefixes": ["http://mymachinename.cloudapp.net/"]
}
```

Comment: what version of Mono are you running?? you can check this by writing the command `mono --version` in a terminal

Comment: It says "Mono JIT compiler version (EventStore patched build: ThreadPool.c) 3.0.12 ((no/d6c5db8 Thu Sep 19 20:01:44 UTC 2013) (EventStore build)".

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade to mono 3.2.3 and test again

Comment: There is no script in the EventStore-Source code to compile a patched version later than 3012.

Comment: mono runs the eventstore, not the other way around, so you should be able to have a mono v3.2.3 installation to run the eventstore, I don't know what scripts are you talking about

Comment: The setup guide I mentioned above says that I have to compile mono with the help of scripts shipped with EventStore. As you can see in the version string of my mono it says that mono is patched. I have no idea what they are doing there but I thought that I need this patched version. I will try it with an unpatched 3.2.3.

Comment: you need a patched version ONLY if your mono version is lower than 3.2.3, as mono 3.2.3 already includes their modifications; they probably need to update their setup guide

Comment: I have the same problem with mono 3.2.3. I have updated the question with my config file. Is there an error/mistake?

Comment: did you disable the firewall?

Comment: No, how should I do that on Ubuntu 13.04 and why I did not need it for port 1113? sudo ufw status says "inaktive". Maybe I should use a windows vm. Seems to be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, problem found.

Yo have to specify the port in the httpPrefix:

My corrected config:

```
{
    "db": "/mnt/datadrive/eventStore/db",
    "logsDir": "/mnt/datadrive/eventStore/logs",
    "ip": "10.26.222.3",
    "httpPrefixes": ["http://mymachinename.cloudapp.net:2113/"]
}
```